# Why type gets infered and generic parameter is optional

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have the following situation. I want to restrict the input of the GridSelectProps to the type passed as a generic paramater and its keys. However, the generic paramater is not mandatory. If I do not pass it, all entries are possible, if I pass it, the restriction works as desired.

I thought it was a simple story, but somehow if the generic paramater is not specified it is interpreted as a string and if the paramater is specified it is restricted to the keys.

How can I achieve the behaviour I want? I want the generic parameter to be a mandatory specification and therefore only inputs that are available as keys in this type are possible.

```
interface Person {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
}

interface Props<T> {
  readonly dataItemKey: keyof T & string;
}

const GridSelectProps = <T>({ dataItemKey }: Props<T>): GridProps => {
  return {
    dataItemKey,
  };
};

const somePropsWithout = GridSelectProps({
  dataItemKey: "Test" // compiler does not complain
});

const somePropsWith = GridSelectProps<PdsrOverviewItem>({
  dataItemKey: "Id", // compiler assignment check works as expected
});
```

[codesandbox playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/type-inference-riwrcd)

Answer (score 1):

When using a generic type or function without specifying the argument, TS will try to figure out what the value would be. This is called *type argument inference*.

In your case, you are calling the generic function `GridSelectProps<T>` without specifying `T`:

```
const GridSelectProps = <T>({ dataItemKey }: Props<T>): GridProps =>

const somePropsWithout = GridSelectProps({
  dataItemKey: "Test"
});
```

Now TS infers that `T` is `{Test: any}` and everything works out.

You can pull the `Props<T>` into the constraint to avoid this:

```
const GridSelectProps = <T, P extends Props<T> = Props<T>>({ dataItemKey }: P): GridProps => {
  return {
    dataItemKey
  }
}
```

Comment: `T` is not a generic constraint, it's a generic type parameter.